# How can I plot the dataframe in seaborn bar?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I have a problem about drawing a seaborn bar plot in terms of this dataframe shown below

I created df_total shown below

```
df_total = df[['Confirmed','Recovered','Deaths']].sum()
df_total = df_total.reset_index()
```

Here is my dataframe named for df_total

```
index   0

0   Confirmed   145193

1   Recovered   70251

2   Deaths  5404
```

Plot

```
sns.barplot(x = "", y = ""
            data = df_total )
```

Which x and y values should be determined to draw bar plot?

Comment: How is created `df_total` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for set index name and then add parameter `name` in [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df_total = df[['Confirmed','Recovered','Deaths']].sum()
df_total = df_total.rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')

sns.barplot(x = "a", y = 'b', data = df_total )
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
sns.barplot(x = "index", y = 0, data = df_total)
```